# Fusion table KML import

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

I used to have no problem importing kmls to fusion tables and making lots of great maps but now it only brings in three columns - name, description and geography.  The remaining attributes show up when a feature is clicked on but you can't make any map setting/theme changes based on any of them and they don't show up in table view. Table view appears to be restricted to name, description and geography. I've tried with multiple datasets.

Is anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Are you using Google Fusion Tables via Google Docs website or the Google Fusion Tables API?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `<Schema>` and `<SchemaData>` elements in your KML then [Google Fusion tables](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/181717?hl=en&ref_topic=1652595) will import those as columns.

```
<ExtendedData>                   
  <SchemaData schemaUrl="anyURI">
    <SimpleData name=""> ... </SimpleData>
  </SchemaData>
</ExtendedData>
```

Likewise, if you use `<Data>` in [ExtendedData](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#extendeddata) for your metadata then that also is imported as columns in the import.

```
<ExtendedData>                       
  <Data name="string">
    <value>...</value>
  </Data>
</ExtendedData>
```

See related tutorial with examples:
https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue with attributes that didn't appear in the first couple of *Placemarks* in the KML document.

The workaround was to either re-arrange the placemarks, or to add the missing attributes with some default value to all placemarks.

No difference if you use *Data* or *SchemaData*.